# Flutter - How to add unmanaged/non-consumable product for in app purchase in test app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

Currently i am performing in app purchase in my test project.

I wanted to add an option in the app for unmanaged/non-consumable product. What i want to do is let say if a user has not purchased an unmanaged/non-consumable product then i will disable some features in the app for the user.

But, if i purchase that unmanaged/non-consumable product then user can access all the app features for the lifetime.

Currently, google play console is showing only managed products and subscriptions tab only. Is there a way to implement in app purchase for unmanaged/non-consumable product in the app ?

Currently i am using the [FlutterInApp](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase/versions/0.6.4#-example-tab-) Plugin for my test project ?

I didn't find documentation for the unmanaged/non-consumable products in flutter anywhere?

Can anyone suggest a worksround?

Thanks.